# Vector component in Python cannot exceed 10 radians

Tags: python, game-engine

I'm using this python code to rotate a bone in the blender game engine, the code works fine until bone angle reaches 10.0 or -10.0 radians then it stops

```
import bge
import mathutils

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
armature = cont.owner

up_pressed = cont.sensors['up_sensor'].positive
down_pressed = cont.sensors['down_sensor'].positive
currentAngle = armature.channels['Bone'].rotation_euler 

speed = 0.1
increment = mathutils.Vector((0.0, speed, 0.0))

if up_pressed:
    armature.channels['Bone'].rotation_mode = bge.logic.ROT_MODE_XYZ
    armature.channels['Bone'].rotation_euler  = currentAngle + increment
    armature.update()

if down_pressed:
    armature.channels['Bone'].rotation_mode = bge.logic.ROT_MODE_XYZ
    armature.channels['Bone'].rotation_euler  = currentAngle - increment
    armature.update()    

print(currentAngle)
```

I guess it has something to do with the `mathutils.Vector` type but I can't figure it out.

is there another way to handle .rotation_euler data other than vectors?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easy answer is just replace your actual rotation statements with an if statement that says something like the following:

**up_pressed:**

```
if armature.channels['Bone'].rotation_euler.y < 2*math.pi:
    armature.channels['Bone'].rotation_euler.y = currentAngle + increment
else:
    armature.channels['Bone'].rotation_euler.y = 0
```

**down_pressed:**

```
if armature.channels['Bone'].rotation_euler.y > 0:
    armature.channels['Bone'].rotation_euler.y = currentAngle - increment
else:
    armature.channels['Bone'].rotation_euler.y = 2*math.pi
```

Comment: thank you, you led me to an even better solution for more smooth rotation: "else: armature.channels['Bone'].rotation_euler = currentAngle - 2*math.pi", pi cannot be written directly, so I used math,pi after importing "math" module

Comment: @AhmedAli Good call on the math.pi, I will edit for future correctness. I'm glad that helped you.

Comment: sorry, I forgot something else, 'armature.channels['Bone'].rotation_euler' is a vector, it can't be compared to zero directly, I needed to compare the component value instead, for example 'armature.channels['Bone'].rotation_euler.y > 0'